# Can't enter edit mode after making proxy from linked object

Tags: objects

So I linked my object into a scene and then made it into a proxy with ctrl alt P, but now I can't enter Edit mode for some of the objects in my scene ?

Comment: Are you editing link object or you want to edit proxy

Comment: I want to edit proxy (orange border around the mesh, not blue)